# CSS: how can I transition flex-basis from 0 to 100%?

Tags: css, flexbox, transition

i want to transition element height to fit content on hover, but transition only works with px value and not % value. om % value it just show whole content without transition.

```
.wrap {
                width: 1000px;
                background-color: green;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
            }
            .first {
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: red;
            }
            .second {
                flex: 1;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            .txt {
                flex-shrink: 1;
                flex-grow: 1;
                flex-basis: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                
            }

            .txt:hover {
                flex-basis: 100%;
                transition: flex-basis 500ms ease-in-out;
            }
```

```
<div class="wrap">
            <div class="first"></div>
            <div class="second">
                <h1>test</h1>
                <div class="txt">
                    <p>akljf jdfklask fjaks jklaj klaj klajl jakl jkaj ajl jalk jajk ča dkls djaklflakdj fklaj kj kljakl jkla flkaj klfjakl jfklaj klaj fkjaklj klaj klfjakl jfklaj klfjalk jkla jkja lkjflak jkla jkajk </p>
                    <p>akljf jdfklask fjaks jklaj klaj klajl jakl jkaj ajl jalk jajk ča dkls djaklflakdj fklaj kj kljakl jkla flkaj klfjakl jfklaj klaj fkjaklj klaj klfjakl jfklaj klfjalk jkla jkja lkjflak jkla jkajk </p>
                    <p>akljf jdfklask fjaks jklaj klaj klajl jakl jkaj ajl jalk jajk ča dkls djaklflakdj fklaj kj kljakl jkla flkaj klfjakl jfklaj klaj fkjaklj klaj klfjakl jfklaj klfjalk jkla jkja lkjflak jkla jkajk </p>
                </div>
                <h2>test 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

if i set flex-basis on hover to some high px value it works as expected but doesnt fit content.

Comment: I don't believe this possible. Flex basis is not the same as height. What you are essentially trying to do, I believe, is transitioning to auto and that is not possible with CSS.